# how to block the main thread to wait until completion block is over

Tags: multithreading, swift

i used assetForURL() to find the NSData of the image  and using this data i find the md5  value of NSData

```
var imageData  = NSData()
self.assetsLibrary.assetForURL(url, resultBlock: {
            (asset: ALAsset!) in
            if asset != nil {
                let assetRep: ALAssetRepresentation! = asset.defaultRepresentation()
                let sizeOfRawDataInBytes: Int = Int(assetRep.size())
                var rawData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData(length: sizeOfRawDataInBytes)!
                var bufferPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = rawData.mutableBytes
                var bufferPtr8: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(bufferPtr)

                var error: NSError? = nil
                assetRep.getBytes(bufferPtr8, fromOffset: 0, length: sizeOfRawDataInBytes, error: &error)

                imageData = NSData(bytesNoCopy: bufferPtr8, length: sizeOfRawDataInBytes, freeWhenDone: false)

            }
            }, failureBlock: {
                (error: NSError!) in

                NSLog("Error!")
            }


        )




   //want to block until completion block is finished execution
var data = imageData // give me output zero bytes
var hash = imageData.md5
```

by making some research i found that the main thread is not waiting for completion block to finish execute

please some one help to block the main thread until my completion block is executed

Comment: It shouldn't wait. Why do you want it to?

Comment: because first of all i run the above code in For loop and it will give me the fetal error

Comment: Blocking the main thread is probably the worst idea. It will freeze your UI

Comment: I concur with @zisoft. You need to use callback to get the data you want.

Comment: can you refer some example of callBack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to block the main thread, it will be bad for you and the user.

Instead, in the block, once you have the image data and the MD5 ready, you should switch back to the main thread (using `dispatch_async` or `performSelectorOnMainThread...`) and update your UI with the new data. You can either store the image data in an instance variable before doing that or pass it as a parameter to the method you call (the main thread block will capture it if you use the dispatch approach).

In this way you are embracing the asynchronous nature of what you're trying to do and utilising the multi-threading capability of iOS to make life good for your user.

Comment: can u refer me some example related to this?

Comment: Example of `dispatch_async` ? You need to be more specific, start typing that an Xcode will offer to auto-complete the code block for you, then you can add your code using the `imageData` into there.

Comment: i used dispatch_async and put my give code in that it will give me fetal error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: You're onto a new question really, and it's probably best to raise it separately. You'll need to show the code and explain what is nil unexpectedly.

Comment: no i just want to wait until completion block is executed.        as in my give code  completion block give ImageData in bytes  but as my main thread not wait for completion block it will execute the line       var data = imageData and there i will get error

Comment: And you're supposed to be moving that code that uses `imageData` into the block called by `dispatch_async` - the main thread should not be made to wait.

Comment: thanks for your help Wain, i will put my whole code in completion block it will work fine for me